# PyQT6 could not find QT platform plugin "cocoa" in ""

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt6

I have a problem with PyQT6 on MacOS 14 (M1)

I am fully aware this problem is pretty common and I have browsed many threads regarding this issue, but no solutions found online have helped me yet. I am not sure if I am missing something .

I'm currently writing GUI for my local Python application using 'venv'. It is very small and doesn't have many packages installed except these:

```
numpy==1.26.1
opencv-contrib-python==4.8.1.78
PyPDF2==3.0.1
PyQt6==6.6.0
PyQt6-Qt6==6.6.0
PyQt6-sip==13.6.0
Unidecode==1.3.7
```

When installing PyQt6 everything seems to work just fine. Interface appears upon launching the script and functions properly.
The issue that I am dealing is, that when running the script after some time (like day or two), it starts throwing me this error message:

> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

As suggested, deleting the package using pip uninstall and manually deleting it from venv, then reinstalling it fixes the problem, but after some time it is still occurring.

This is my code which works fine after fresh install:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QLabel

class DirectoryChooserApp(QWidget):
    selected_directory = ""  # Class variable to store the selected directory

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        # Create layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # Create button
        btn_choose_directory = QPushButton('Choose Directory', self)
        btn_choose_directory.clicked.connect(self.choose_directory)

        # Create label to display selected directory
        self.lbl_selected_directory = QLabel('Selected Directory: ', self)

        # Add button and label to layout
        layout.addWidget(btn_choose_directory)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl_selected_directory)

        # Set layout for the main window
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # Set up the main window
        self.setWindowTitle('Directory Chooser App')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 200)

    def choose_directory(self):
        # Open a directory dialog
        directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select Directory')

        if directory:
            self.selected_directory = directory
            self.lbl_selected_directory.setText(f'Selected Directory: {directory}')

            # Here you can perform actions with the selected directory
            print(f'Selected Directory: {directory}')

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = DirectoryChooserApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am not sure, if the issue is inside the code itself as it seemed to work fine. It just asks user to specify directory and then shows it.

Does anyone have a working solution for this problem? I find it weird that it works fine for x amount of time and then just decides to stop.

Comment: Assuming that everything is in order, that's weird indeed. I'd start by creating an *extremely* minimal code, with all things in place (requirements, convention and environment): if the problem doesn't present anymore with that, you have a valid starting point to begin with; that's how proper debugging is achieved in general: get to the point, without distractions (it's also the reason for which we usually ask for a [mre]). The following will probably suffice: `import sys` `from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *` `app = QApplication(sys.argv)` `test = QWidget()` `test.show()` `sys.exit(app.exec())`.